# Multiple Magento websites with store view codes as language codes

Tags: magento

I was comfortable handling multilanguage setups using store views, setting each store view's code to it's respective language shortcode (de, fr, en, ...). Then enabled "Add Store Code to URLS" and everyone was happy, it just worked.

This time it's somewhat more complicated. I have a Magento installation with multiple websites, one for each contry, and some of them have common language codes.

For example, imagine that I have a website for both Canada and Belgium. The first one will support French and English as navigation languages and the latter one French, Dutch and German.

Since both sites have common navigation languages (French), I cannot use the language shortcode as the store view code, as these ones must be unique. I could prefix the website name to the store view code site1_fr, site2_fr, but as the store code is meant to be shown on the url, this will lead to ugly and somewhat redundant urls: site1.ca/site1_fr instead of just site1.ca/fr.

Is there some kind of workaround in order to hide these ugly store codes?

Perhaps some mod_rewrite magic and Magento config changes would do the trick?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: OF course there are workarounds to do anything, but you haven't said what you want. If you want to redirect e.g. /somestore/ to /site1_fr/, then why not just use the code "somestore" in the first place? Tell us what you want TO happen, not just what you want to NOT happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution for make stores with same language codes , like shirts.com/en and shoes.com/en - https://gist.github.com/arosenhagen/5256617

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the link below:
http://www.crucialwebhost.com/blog/how-to-setup-multiple-magento-stores/

Comment: He asked for a way o get around the "ugly store codes" and I provided a link that has a solution for his problem. I can't see how this isn't related ;)

Comment: The question is, with multiple websites/stores, how can he be able to use the store view code "en" for different store views, 1 for each websites/store...

Comment: Each website would go on a different domain. (Eg the Belgian website - Dutch language would be website.be/nl and Belgian website - French language would be website.be/fr. French website would be website.fr , ... This is perfectly possible with the solution I provided.

Comment: No it isnt, your solution would have shoes.com/shoes_en/ and shirts.com/shirts_en/ which is the kind of thing we want to avoid.  We just want shirts.com/en and shoes.com/en on the same installation

Answer (score 0):

I want to second the idea of using a different domain or subdomain for the different language store views.
Otherwise you will have pages with the same url but different content; probably not optimal for your sites SEO, or be forced to use the 'add store code to urls' config which has never seemed to work completely right in my experience.